# How can I search for all documents with _id in an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to search for all documents with an `_id` that is in an array of id's. Here is what I have so far, but it is returning nothing:

```
var myArray = [53950fe210bcef043aa6e135, 5394f5be2f6953083908db47];
User.find(
    {_id: { $in : myArray }},
    null,
    {},
    function (err, data) {
        if (!err){
            return res.json(data);
        }
    }
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your array only has one element in it with a single string.  I think what you want is to put close quote in front of and behind the comma to make it an array with two ID strings.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The quotes weren't supposed to be there. I still am unable to get it to work though.

Comment: I think you still need the quotes there... I don't know how javascript will interpret the "naked" ids.  Try it with quotes around the ids (making them strings).  Specifically: "var myArray = ["53950fe210bcef043aa6e135", "5394f5be2f6953083908db47"];"